# MalformedPolicyDocumentExceptionnull AWS KMS KEY

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

Am trying to create a KMS KEY using cloudformation with below template, am getting an error as

```
Error:
MalformedPolicyDocumentExceptionnull (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocumentException; Request ID: cc99c04e-8423-43a3-9183-313438544abb)
```

I have tried many ways to fix this issue but couldn't a find a solution.

```
Template:

PcsKmsCmk1:
    Type: AWS::KMS::Key
    Properties:
      KeyPolicy:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Id: default
        Statement:
          - Sid: Allow root account all permissions except to decrypt the key
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
               - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root
            Action: kms:*
            Resource: '*'
          - Sid: Enable AWSAdminRole to have full permissions to KMS key
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:/role/AWSAdminRole
            Action: kms:*
            Resource: '*'
        Condition:
              Bool:
                 kms:GrantIsForAWSResource: 'true'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ARN, you used `/role` which is wrong.

[For you reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html)

Use `- !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/AWSAdminRole` instead of `- !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:/role/AWSAdminRole`